# Why is an output parameter is expected in this stored procedure?

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures

I have written a simple stored procedure with some output parameters, but when I execute it from my C# code, I get an error

> Expects Parameters

It is expecting me provide values for the `OUTPUT` parameters ...

Please help me figure out the error ...

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Check_EntryTrade_value] 
    @Account_ID bigint,
    @Date datetime2(7),
    @tradeby varchar(20),
    @Symbol varchar(20),
    @B_S varchar(20),
    @RateE float ,
    @Usd_Marg bigint OUTPUT,
    @Amount bigint OUTPUT,
    @Rate float OUTPUT,
    @Entry_Order_id bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @Rate = [Rate], 
        @Entry_Order_id = [EntryOrder_ID],
        @Amount = [Amount],
        @Usd_Marg = [Usd_Mrg]  
    FROM  
        [dbo].[entrytable] 
    WHERE
        [B_S]  = @B_S 
        AND [Rate] = @RateE 
        AND [Account_ID] = @Account_ID 
        AND [Symbol] = @Symbol;

    IF (@Rate IS NOT NULL)
       INSERT INTO neworder (Account_ID, Symbol, B_S, Rate, Amount, Date, Usd_Marg, tradeby) 
       VALUES(@Account_ID, @Symbol, @B_S, @Rate, @Amount, @Date, @Usd_Marg, @tradeby);

    DELETE FROM entrytable WHERE EntryOrder_ID = @Entry_Order_id;
END
```

And this is my C# Code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyCon);
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//SQL INJECTION '"+ +"'
cmd.CommandText = "Check_EntryTrade_value";
SqlParameter pID1 = new SqlParameter("@Account_ID", SqlDbType.BigInt, 10);
pID1.Value = 1;
SqlParameter pID2 = new SqlParameter("@Symbol", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
pID2.Value = "EUR/USD";
SqlParameter pID3 = new SqlParameter("@B_S", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
pID3.Value = "Buy";
SqlParameter pID4 = new SqlParameter("@RateE", SqlDbType.Float, 10);
pID4.Value = 1.24763;
//SqlParameter pID6 = new SqlParameter("@Amount", SqlDbType.BigInt, 10);
//pID6.Value = 1;
SqlParameter pID5 = new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 7);
pID5.Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
SqlParameter pID6 = new SqlParameter("@tradeby", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
pID6.Value = "User";

cmd.Parameters.Add(pID1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID2);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID3);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID4);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID5);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID6);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Running my C# code returns this error:

> Procedure or Function 'Check_EntryTrade_value' expects parameter '@Usd_Marg', which was not supplied.

Comment: You need to add SqlParameters for the output parameters as well. Check their Value after you execute it. How else are you expecting to get their values?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, i dont want any ouput from the Stored procedure i just want it to be Executed after giving it, its Required Fields,

Answer (score 1):

I Found it :) .. Thanks Every One for Help .. i love StackOverFlow :P

Here is what i did :

```
//STEP-1 CONNECTION
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyCon);
  //STEP-2 COmmand
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//SQL INJECTION '"+ +"'
cmd.CommandText = "Check_EntryTrade_value";


SqlParameter pID1 = new SqlParameter("@Account_ID", SqlDbType.BigInt, 10);
pID1.Value = 1;
SqlParameter pID2 = new SqlParameter("@Symbol", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
pID2.Value = "EUR/USD";
SqlParameter pID3 = new SqlParameter("@B_S", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
pID3.Value = "Buy";
SqlParameter pID4 = new SqlParameter("@RateE", SqlDbType.Float, 10);
pID4.Value = 1.24763;
//SqlParameter pID6 = new SqlParameter("@Amount", SqlDbType.BigInt, 10);
//pID6.Value = 1;
SqlParameter pID5 = new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime2, 7);
pID5.Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
SqlParameter pID6 = new SqlParameter("@tradeby", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
pID6.Value = "User";

SqlParameter pID7 = new SqlParameter("@Usd_Marg", SqlDbType.BigInt, 10);
pID7.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
// pID6.Value = "User";
SqlParameter pID8 = new SqlParameter("@Amount", SqlDbType.BigInt, 20);
pID8.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
//  pID6.Value = "User";
SqlParameter pID9 = new SqlParameter("@Rate", SqlDbType.BigInt, 20);
pID9.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
// pID6.Value = "User";
SqlParameter pID10 = new SqlParameter("@Entry_Order_id", SqlDbType.BigInt, 20);
pID10.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
// pID6.Value = "User";




cmd.Parameters.Add(pID1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID2);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID3);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID4);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID5);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID6);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID7);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID8);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID9);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pID10);
```

Comment: Actually, this should be `using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyCon) { using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) { // rest of the code }}`

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove

```
@Usd_Marg bigint OUTPUT,
@Amount bigint OUTPUT,
@Rate float OUTPUT,
@Entry_Order_id bigint OUTPUT
```

from stored procedure definition .

Modify your query :

```
SELECT [Rate], [EntryOrder_ID],[Amount],[Usd_Mrg]  
FROM [dbo].[entrytable] 
WHERE [B_S]  = @B_S AND [Rate] = @RateE AND [Account_ID] = @Account_ID AND [Symbol] = @Symbol;
```

On the C# side you will receive a data set so you need to change last line of c# code :

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```